# MochaJS: Rejected promises not triggering a failed test

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, supertest

I'm using async-await syntax with Mocha and Supertest. This is my problematic test:

```
it('Test POST/friends route: should add a friendship', async function () {       
    const lastFriendship =   await models.Friendship.findAll({limit: 1,where: {},order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ]]})
    const lastFriendId = lastFriendship[0].id

    await request(app)
        .post('/friends')
        .set('Authorization', token)
        .send({ friendId: 998 })
        .expect(200)
        .expect(async (res) => {
            console.log('res.data', res.body.data.id)
            const newFriendId = res.body.data.id
            expect(res.body.data.friendId).toEqual(998)
            expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('error', null);
            expect(newFriendId - lastFriendId).toBe(2)//This should fail the test.
        })        
})
```

The last assertion,as it's written now, should fail the test, but instead i receive this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>   expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

I tried putting the entire thing in try-catch block, with no success. I'm obviously missing something about the mechanics here.

What is wrong with my code?

EDIT: removing the "async" from the callback function of expect, solves it, though i don't know why throwing an exception in a callback doesn't get caught here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse your res.body as JSON.

Comment: Nah, the problem is that im using an async function as the expect callback. Once i removed it - it works. But i do not have the knowledge/understanding as to why it happens.

Comment: I use async functions in mocha.  They're fine.  I don't see how you can do an await without an async in the function signature.

Comment: Yes, but i'm talkign about the callback to the last expect call. I do not use "await" there. Anyway, removing the async from it solves it, which implies that i do not really understand how exceptions and promises work :D

Comment: Yes, I have a similar problem.  Just when I think I know how they work, one bites me.